# Symplectic forms are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request, symplectic-linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a symplectic vector space, i.e. a vector space with a non-degenerate  alternating bilinear form, a so-called symplectic form. There is a theorem:

> All symplectic forms on $V$ are ismorphic.

I have two questions about this:

1) Can somebody explain what it means precisely that two symplectic forms are isomorphic?

2) Could somebode give references on this statement with or without proof?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be proven that any finite-dimensional symplectic vector space of dimension $2n$ has a basis in which the symplectic form $\omega$ has the form:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & I_n \\
-I_n & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

This proves that two symplectic forms are isomorphic. A reference is [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_space#Standard_symplectic_space).

Comment: Merci! And what does it mean if two such forms are isomorphic?

Comment: It means that for any $\omega_1,\omega_2$ two symplectic forms, you can find an invertible linear transformation $\varphi$ such that for any $x,y \in V$ $\omega_1(x,y) = \omega_2(\varphi(x),\varphi(y))$.

Comment: So, "Two symplectic vector-spaces of equal dimension are isomorphic" is right as well?

Comment: Ate isomorphic as symplectic spaces. Yes. Any two real Vector spaces of same dimensions are isomorphic in general.

Comment: What does ate mean?